# MySQL - Getting Days of the Week

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with special offers for Mon -Sun. I wish to get the next offer available from the today. In the table the days have a numerical value 1-7

Eg.

```
1(mon)-offer1

2(tues)-offer2

3(wed)-offer3

6(Sat)-offer4
```

If today is Sun DAYOFWEEK 7 then the offer I wish to get back is offer1 which is the next available mon DAYOFWEEK 1. If today was Friday then I would get offer4.

Here is the SQL that I have. The problem is that I cannot get the offer1 scenario to work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM special_offers  
WHERE special_offers.special_day >= IF(DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1>0,DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1,7) 
  AND special_offers.pubID = 48 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: just making sure.  typo for Sat?  should be 4?  At least Monday and Sat shouldn't be the same.

Comment: you can use php's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, like this: `date("w", strtotime("now"));`

Comment: The sql works fine for scenario where  If today was Friday DAYOFWEEK 5 then I would get offer4 which is the next day DAYOFWEEK 6. But if today is Sunday then the next offer is Mon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the return value from the MySQL DAYOFWEEK() function has 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday.  So if your table has 1 for Monday and 7 for Sunday, you need to adjust by 1.

Second, what you need is modular arithmetic.  Does this work for you?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM special_offers
 ORDER BY (special_offers.special_day + 8 - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) MOD 7
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks for that is it, would never have though of it. Thanks to everyone else for the help also. Not easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that for MySQL **DAYOFWEEK** function Mondey is equal to 2 and Sundey is equal to 1, look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).

Simple workaround for your problem is to use if statement:

```
IF(DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1>0,DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1,7)
```

This converts days numbers to normal order.

Comment: how? this doesn't normalize days. today is friday and you need to get 5. but "select IF( DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) - 1 > 0, DAYOFWEEK(NOW()), 7);" will return 6 because dayofweek(now) is 6 and 6-1=5>0 will become true to if statement and will return itself.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to add "-1" to statement ;)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However I will have the same problem in that if it is sun then I need to go back and get mondays or the next available offer

Comment: You want to get one next offer from today if I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is the expected and actual values but what I understand you want this as a result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM special_offers  
WHERE special_offers.special_day >= case DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) when 1 then 7 when 2 then 1 when 3 then 2 when 4 then 3 when 5 then 4 when 6 then 5 when 7 then 6 end
AND special_offers.pubID = 48
LIMIT 1
```

Edit:
This will try to find next available special offer from todays till sunday, and if it doesn't find, it will find the very first special offer.

```
SELECT *
FROM  special_offers so
WHERE so.pubID=48
ORDER BY 
if(special_day = case DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) when 1 then 7 when 2 then 1 when 3 then 2 when 4 then 3 when 5 then 4 when 6 then 5 when 7 then 6 end, 1, 0) desc, so.special_day
limit 1
```

Comment: If today is Fri which is DAYOFWEEK 5 then the sql will bring back the entry for sat which is DAYOFWEEK 6. My problem is that if it is sunday which is 7 then I need to get monday which is the next offer. I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: If I understand correctly I made a change. (not sure I understand correctly whole weeks expectation so test my query)

Comment: Hi Nesim, my proble is not that I need to normalise the DAYOFWEEK order(although I do need to do this as this can casue an issue). What I am trying to solve is if today is the end of the week then my query will not get the next offer as it starts again at 1. The >= will only get a result if it is at the start

Comment: ok my last edit has to solve both your problems? did you try? Your table holds offer days 1-7 (mon-sun), mysql dayofweek return 0-7 (sun-sat) so you need to normalize is your first problem. You want if todays is sunday, you want to act like monday is your second problem. This is what ı understand from all comments. And my last edit has to solve both.

Comment: I did thanks Nesim, I am still not getting a record, I need it that it will keep going through the days until it get a record until it come back to the same day. Today is DAYOFWEEK 5, my next record is for DAYOFWEEK 1 which is Mon, It is not finding that. I hope that helps to narrow it down

Comment: I think it is more clear now (I hope so) Please check my edit but you need to know it is really very hard to understand expectations with these informations.